# Clonezilla - if I need Live DVD, why bother installing?

Tags: 15.04, clonezilla, cloning

I am running 15.04 (with LVM) and I want to create an iso image of my SDD. Installed Clonezilla (`sudo apt-get install clonezilla`) and tried to use the tool from within 15.04. It tells me "`Error! No existing partitions(s) or no unmounted partition(s) are found! To use Clonezilla to save or clone a partition, the source partition must exist or be unmounted! ..`."

Did a bit more reading on Clonezilla, and the usual practice appears to be to burn the Clonezilla Live DVD, boot from that, and then clone/restore your primary Ubuntu image. If this is the recommended practice - I have to ask, why is Clonezilla available as a application that can be installed within a Ubuntu instance?

For convenience, I would prefer to just clone my SDD from within a running 15.04 instance (as I do with Acronis TrueImage from within my Windows 8 install). Not possible?

FYI, I have the following configuration `sda` -> [`sda1`, `sda5` -> [`root`, `swap_1`]]. i.e. just one physical SDD with LVM installed.

I don't mind using some other tool (other than Clonezilla) if that would allow me to clone from within my running Ubuntu instance.

Thanks.

Comment: So... you're looking to take a live image, then, basically, of your system?  (`ext` partitions don't like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful where you have set up a multi-partition environment in which you have a data drive/partition that you want to back up. That is, you can unmount that partition without making important parts of your system unavailable.

I don't know of any Linux tools that will take an image of a mounted system. I use a bootable USB pendrive with CloneZilla on it which seems convenient to me. http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php .

If you just want to backup some files you could look at rsync .

Answer (score 2):

Running Clonezilla within Ubuntu allows you to clone *unmounted* drives. Cloning a drive while it is mounted can and will cause damage. I am not sure how it is possible to clone like how you mentioned in Windows, unless the drive is unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

The installed-in-Ubuntu tool is designed to be used with other drives and unmounted partitions - such as an external USB drive, or a separate internal disk, etc.

As has been mentioned before, CloneZilla needs an unmounted partition to work safely.  It cannot live-image your current root partition.

I do not know how Acronis TrueImage works, as it sounds proprietary and Windows only, however it could be doing a live-image of the system (storing partition data and filesystem data, then live-traversing the file system and grabbing data off it), in a similar fashion to how forensic analysts live-image seized machines.  However, without further information on the inner workings of Acronis' tools, the only thing we can say is "Windows and Ubuntu are different, and have their own quirks."